# Functional way to update a property in one array from another array?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am trying to get into functional programming and after creating a number of pure functions, I have two arrays where I need to create a new array which is the first array with one of its properties updated from the second array.

I have a commands array and a seconds integer array.

The commands array has objects like this :

```
  var SerialCommand = function(serialString, waitTime) {
      this.serialString = serialString;
      this.waitTime = waitTime;
  }
```

Seconds is simply an integer array with the same number of elements as the commands array.

What I want is finally an array where each element of commands array has the following update to it:

```
  command.waitTime = numSeconds;
```

I have created the following function:

```
    var updateSeconds = function(command, numSeconds) {
        command.waitTime = numSeconds;
        return command;
    }
```

but not sure how to combine it with the arrays.

I am using Ramda for my library but any help with any other library will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R.zipWith() seems to be the right thing for you.
http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/docs/#zipWith

Comment: Thank you so much. I only know a hand full and now I know one more..I wasn't even sure you could have functions with more than one parameter (still learning FP). Thank you again.

Comment: Generally in FP, you want to be dealing with immutable values, so in conjunction with `zipWith`, you might want to consider [`R.assoc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc): `R.zipWith(R.assoc('waitTime'), newTimes, commands);`.  You can see an example at http://bit.ly/1Y9PvHw

Comment: Thank Scott, that is amazing. I'll be more careful with the immutability concerns in the future. I am about to post another FP/Ramda question :)